# Does a randomly initialized high-dimensional vector have truly random values in every direction?

Tags: normal-distribution

**X** is a set of high-dimensional vectors that follow an independent and identically distributed (i.i.d) pattern. Is the density of these vectors the same in different **directions** in high-dimensional space?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am just too stupid. This is obvious, as can be inferred from the probability distribution of the normal distribution.

Comment: Yes, if the iid distribution is normal.  On the other hand, if it is uniform distribution, so the possible vectors form a square, or cube etc  then directions near the corners are more likely than directions near the axes.